# Custom post type - columns order

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

So I have created a custom post type with custom values and customize my custom post type admin columns.

**You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySMtf.png) how my custom post type is looking in admin panel.**

And as you can see I can order by title all posts and I was wondering if I could do same for all columns, like "info" etc.

Is it possible?

I am using this code, to display columns like I wanna :

```
//display catalog products in nice list
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "catalog_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-catalog_columns", "catalog_edit_columns");

function catalog_edit_columns($columns){
  $columns = array(
    "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
    "title" => "Product Title",
    "description" => "Info",
    "skills" => "Category",
     "year" => "Price",

  );

  return $columns;
}



function catalog_custom_columns($column){
  global $post;

  switch ($column) {
    case "description":
      the_content();
      break;
     case "skills":
      echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'atrakcijas', '', ', ','');
      break;
    case "year":
      $custom = get_post_custom();
      echo $custom["product_price"][0]; ?>Ls<?php
      break;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scribu as written a great detailed tutorial named "[**Create your own sortable columns**](http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-sortable-columns.html)" just what you need.